# exporting huge dynamic data to csv. million of records to csv

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, linq-to-entities, export-to-csv

we were testing the capability of our application, here is the scenario, we have a table that holds 5 million record, we want to export it to csv so we successfully made a csv writer class. the main problem is when we export the whole record, we catch OOM exception(out of memory exception), when the data is over a million, what makes it more difficult is the user can choose what columns are to be exported..
 is there any way to catch thing up nice and well without a blocking process??? what type of process is best suitable for this scenario??? should i used (and how) to use background process for this??

any point of view (examples) are well appreciated. thanks...

Comment: Study, work out a solution, ask, improve. Try first.

Comment: i have implemented a solution sir, it works for millions of records, when it reachers 5 million it throws exception... i am asking question to improve that part..

Comment: @Raptor as i say any point of view will do

Answer (score 5):

Well it's difficult to answer with such a short description.
Based on your tags; it seems it's a ASP.NET MVC4 based website.
Also it seems; you are trying to create the CSV on-the-fly. (i.e. within the single http call)
I personally would prefer an AJAX based solution where the sequence will be as follows.

1. User initiates the export.
2. Server receives the export request and starts a background job to create the CSV file. (possibly in a different process) and return the status saying job started (With Job ID).
3. Implement a mechanism to monitor this job. Possible a DB entry about the job status and progress.
4. At front-end a periodic AJAX call checks the job status; and shows progress to the user.
5. Once the job finishes; provide a download link for user to download your huge file.

With proper implementation; this approach has the following benefits.

- It's Non blocking and interactive.
- It can handle really huge jobs.
- User gets an opportunity to cancel the job.
- Each job runs in a separate process; giving it it's own memory space.
- It can be scaled to multiple servers.

Although as you can see; it has it's own overheads.

Comment: exactly sir @malay but i dont have enough knowledge on that background job, i am currently looking at capability of signal r hence it is a long pooling but with the background work i dont have a starting point yet

Comment: i am also looking to a web service sir for a possible approach

Answer (score 0):

use **file helpers library** see article

@  [FileHelpers throws OutOfMemoryException when parsing large csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15233454/filehelpers-throws-outofmemoryexception-when-parsing-large-csv-file)

you can get it via nuget

Comment: This is a borderline [link-only answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231/213671). You should expand your answer to include as much information here, and use the link only for reference.